# How to send jQuery table to Mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have created the table using jquery to increase the number of rows on click on add row. And the question is that I want to send the table data to database and I don't have any idea how to do that. Please any one can help me. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code that I have used to create the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
form{
    margin: 20px 0;
}
form input, button{
    padding: 5px;
}
table{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
table th, table td{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Add table row
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var name = $("#model").val();
        var email = $("#imei").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td id= 'name'>" + name + "</td><td id='email'>" + email + "</td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="model" id="model" placeholder="Model">
    <input type="text" name="imei" id="imei" placeholder="IMEI No.">
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>IMEI</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <!-- the table will be inserted from jquery -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
<button type="button" >Save</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Search "ajax" on google

Answer (score 1):

you must use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this

```
$(".add-row").click(function(){
    var name = $("#model").val();
    var email = $("#imei").val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { nm: name , em: email  }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td id= 'name'>" + name + "</td><td id='email'>" + email + "</td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
      });

});
```